# Django | ModelMultipleChoiceField ERROR

Tags: python, django, django-models

Se pretende que el siguiente modelo dé opción a que se pueda seleccionar una o varias opciones de la tabla `Employee` de entre los resultados del filtro.

Pero devuelve error:

```
in Preventive
    employee_preventive = models.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(company="Example123"))
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ModelMultipleChoiceField'
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Preventive(models.Model):
    #...
    employee_preventive = models.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(company="Example123"))
    #...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Mant Preventivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mant Preventivos'
        ordering = ['id']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: el model se define con `models.LoQueSea(choices=...)`

Answer (score 1):

No se de donde sacas [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield), pues es un **campo de formulario**, es mas, el mismo error te dice que el modulo `django.db.models` no tiene el atributo [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

No se si estas confundido respecto al campo o al modelo (lo cual me parece muy raro), pero si quieres usar el **campo de formulario [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) seria en un form:**

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField
>>>
```

Al igual que @DiegoPuente pienso que a lo mejor necesitas una relación *muchos a muchos* (`ManyToManyField`) ya que es un *multiple choice*.

Answer (score 0):

Como pones multiplechoice imagino que entre el modelo Preventive y Employee deberia haber una relacion de many to many, por ende el modelo quedaria asi:

```
class Preventive(models.Model):
    #...
    employee_preventive = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, related_name="preventives", limit_choices_to={"company": "Example123"})
    #...
```

con esto se va a poder elegir uno o varios employees.